# Using JWT & Basic auth based on called resource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, basic-authentication

I have an api running on spring boot along with spring security.
The app manages state with JWTs. The initial call issues a fresh JWT and all subsequent calls need to have it to get through spring security.

There is a new requirement for a couple of new endpoints (with uniquely identifiable resource paths)that are secured through basic auth. There would be no need for JWTs in this context.

So my question is, is it even possible to get both JWTs & Basic auth going in a single boot application ? Is it valid to think that I could direct auth requests to different auth filters/providers using an antMatcher on the resource path ?